# How can I put JSON in user_data in terraform?

Tags: json, terraform

If there is any way to put JSON like this

```
{"status":"0","serial":"0"}
```

to user_data without using file ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `heredoc` syntax

(below codes don't work in a real ec2 instance, just show you how to use `heredoc` in terrafrom configuration file. )

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  user_data = <<EOF
{"status":"0","serial":"0"}
EOF
}
  tags {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

Comment: It returns {\"status\":\"0\",\"serial\":\"0\"} and I can implement it straight without heredoc, bu thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSON formatted configuration file, you can do like this

```
{
    "variable": {
       "user_data": {
          "type": "map",
          "default": {
            "status":"0",
            "serial":"0"
          }
       }
    },
    "resource": {
        "aws_instance": {
          "web": {
            "user_data":"${var.user_data}"
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Terraform renurns an error `user_data must be a single value, not a map`